# Multiple columns validation different array

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a problem validating a form in Laravel 8. I have a form select input **days_id** and **hours_id** with each column having multiple rows like this [form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y36Ok.png) .
I want to do unique validation for those 2 columns together, so data is not duplicated in DB and show which inputs are invalid. My table **schedules** structure [schedules table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4x4e.png)

The problem is, my request form is array like this [image request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWA0b.png) ,how to validate input **days_id[index]** and **hours_id[index]** with existed columns **days_id** and **hours_id** in DB?

My view

```
       <tr>
          <td class="day">
            <input type="hidden" name="teasubid[]" value="{{ $teacher_subj->id }}">
            <select name="days_id[]" class="form-control selectday">
             @foreach ($days as $day)
              <option value="{{ $day->id }}">
               {{ $day->name }}
              </option>
             @endforeach
            </select>
          </td>
          <td class="hour">
            <select name="hours_id[]" class="form-control selecthour">
              @foreach ($hours as $hour)
              <option value="{{ $hour->id }}">
              {{ $hour->hours }}
              </option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

My ScheduleRequest

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'teacher_classes_id' => 'required',
            'hours_id' => 'required|unique:schedules,hours_id',
            'days_id' => 'required|unique:schedules,days_id'
        ];
    }
```

I have checked this post-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176098/array-validation-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns and [Laravel Validation of two combined columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62401741/laravel-validation-of-two-combined-columns?rq=1) but I am still confused about array validation and using rules in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Array validation can be done with the annotation `.*`.

```
'hours_id.*' => 'required|unique:schedules,hours_id',
'days_id.*' => 'required|unique:schedules,days_id'
```